# 403 Squid error after successful deployment on elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, squid

I'm stuck with the launching of my node.js server and client (nuxt) environments. After successful deployment, both of them started normally (saw that in logs), but I can't access them using a browser because of a 403 squid error.

How could this issue be sold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VPN service was activated in a browser, and this is why squid blocked me.